# Where is the source of my time out error (swi-prolog)?

Tags: performance, prolog

I am having difficulty finding the source of my time-out error, when I run the following code.

`crossword(H1,H2,V3,V1,V2) :- word(H1), word(H2), word(V3), word(V1), word(V2), word(H2) \= word(V2), string_length(H1,3), string_length(H2,7), string_length(V3,6), string_length(V1,4), string_length(V2,5).`

Preceding this section I have a series of words, such as `word("coding")`, `word("is")`, `word("fun")`, ...

I have a lot of words, could this be the problem? Or is it how I have defined my rules?

Comment: Watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_tbL9RjFdo Explains related "N-Queens in Prolog" and "thrashing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chain of five independent unconstrained selections in a row `word(H1), word(H2), word(V3), word(V1), word(V2)` means there will be made *n<sup>5</sup>* choices overall, if you have *n* words defined in your knowledge base.

Instead, move the constraining calls up in the predicate's body, for the wrong choices to fail as early as possible, preventing the futile nested selections from being performed at all:

```
crossword(H1,H2,V3,V1,V2) :- 
    word(H1), string_length(H1,3),
    word(H2), string_length(H2,7),
    word(V3), string_length(V3,6),
    word(V1), ... .
```